# Funtional react : Increment react state after if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

On the click of a start/stop button, i trigger the **handlePlay** function. The handlePlay function in turn, triggers the **playBeat** function. Ideally, the play beat function should console.log 1222122212221222..., until i press the button to stop. At the moment it gives me 111111111111111.**The state of the currentBeat does not increment which is a problem.** I am using the setCurrentBeat to increment the currentbeat by 1 with each render, but this does not seem to increment.

Check out the full code.

```
function App() {
  const [bpm, setBpm] = useState(100);
  const [isplaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [numberOfBeats, SetNumberOfBeats] = useState(4);
  const [currentBeat, setCurrentBeat] = useState(0);
  const increment = useRef(null);
  // const kick = new Audio(audio2);
  // const snare = new Audio(audio3);
  const hey = 1;
  const bey = 2;

  const handlePlay = () => {
    if (isplaying) {
      clearInterval(increment.current);
      setIsPlaying(false);
      setCurrentBeat(0);
    } else {
      increment.current = setInterval(() => {
        // console.log("hello");
        playBeat();
      }, (60 / bpm) * 1000);
      setIsPlaying(true);
      setCurrentBeat(0);
    }
  };

  const playBeat = () => {
    if(currentBeat % numberOfBeats === 0){
      console.log(hey)
    }else{
      console.log(bey)
    }
    setCurrentBeat(currentBeat + 1)
  };

  const handleInc = () => {
    bpm < 300 && setBpm(Number(bpm) + 1);
  };
  const handleDec = () => {
    bpm > 0 && setBpm(bpm - 1);
  };
  const handleSlider = (e) => {
    if (isplaying) {
      clearInterval(increment.current);
      increment.current = setInterval(() => {
        playBeat();
      }, ((60 / bpm) * 1000));
      setCurrentBeat(0)
      setBpm(e.target.value);
    } else {
      setBpm(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Metronome</h1>
      <p>{bpm} BPM</p>

      <button onClick={handleDec}>
        <AiOutlineMinusCircle />
      </button>
      <input
        type="range"
        value={bpm}
        name=""
        id=""
        min={0}
        max={300}
        step="1"
        onChange={handleSlider}
      />

      <button onClick={handleInc}>
        <AiOutlinePlusCircle />
      </button>
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={handlePlay}
        alt={isplaying ? "stop button" : "start button"}
      >
        {isplaying ? "stop" : "start"}
      </button>
      <button>tap tempo</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

The issue is effectively a stale enclosure over the `currentBeat` state value in the `playBeat` callback.

```
increment.current = setInterval(() => {
  // console.log("hello");
  playBeat(); // <-- closed over
}, (60 / bpm) * 1000);
```

`currentBeat` only has the value from when the interval was instantiated and won't update until the interval is reset/reinstantiated.

```
const playBeat = () => {
  if (currentBeat % numberOfBeats === 0) {
    console.log(hey)
  } else {
    console.log(bey)
  }
  setCurrentBeat(currentBeat + 1)
};
```

## Solution

1. Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly update the `currentBeat` state from the previous state value.
2. Move the hey/bey logging into a `useEffect` hook to log as an intentional side-effect.

Example:

```
const playBeat = () => {
  setCurrentBeat((currentBeat) => currentBeat + 1);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(currentBeat % numberOfBeats === 0 ? hey : bey);
}, [currentBeat, numberOfBeats]);
```

[image: Edit funtional-react-increment-react-state-after-if-statement]

Answer (score 1):

when you use setState function in eventHandler or in some function works in asynchronous, you can't guarantee setState reads fresh state. it probably reads stale state.

there are three workaround this.

1. use  useReducer which reducer always references fresh state.
2. use callback function as a parameter of setState.
   in your case, setState(prev => prev +1);
3. save your state values in useRef and ensure your event handler / asynchronous callback function read that ref values. those ref values should be updated each times when component re-render.

as using above workaround is not a ideal way,

there is a [new RFC - useEvent](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/220) has been proposed.

Also, I recommend you handle timeout function in useEffect, not directly in handler.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const nodeTime = setInterval(() => {
     ...
   })

   return () => {
     clearInterval(nodeTime) 
   }
},[someState])
```

Comment: useReducer would overcomplicate this application i feel. The callback function option did not work in this issue. Could you please show me how i could easily implement this with useRef ?

Comment: Also, i agree with what you said about the useEffect, however, i am still looking for a way to implement this useEffect and my handler together.

Comment: i would eventually refactor this application to use, context, reducer and actions. But for now, is there an easy way to get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to incremement a state based on its previous value, you have to do it like so:

```
setCurrentBeat(previous => previous + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, however, this does not work for my current issue.